# $f^{(k)}(z_0)=0$ for all $k\geq0$ implies that $f=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

I'm trying understand that given an analytic function in a domain, if the function and all its derivatives vanish at a point, then, the function itself is zero.

I was told that this is a direct consequence of principle of analytic continuation, but to my understanding, the principle of analytic continuation says that the zeros of an analytic function is isolated. I'm not sure how to connect the two pieces. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the domain is connected. You can write $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ in a open neighborhood $U$ of $0$  and $a_n$ is proportional to $f^{(n)}(0)$. This implies that $f$ vanishes on $U$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand so please let me rephrase it in my understanding. So since the function is analytic, we can show it as a Taylor series centered at $z_0$, as $f(z)=f(z_0)+f'(z_0)z+\frac{f''(z_0)}{2!}z^2+...$, and since each derivative is zero, the function itself is zero? is that what you are saying? So my question here is, what role does the open neighborhood $U$ play here in terms of representing the domain?

Comment: The rest of the argument is the point 2. of the answer of Jonatan Y. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511718/when-a-holomorphic-function-is-identically-0

Comment: If $f$ all the derivative of $f$ at $x$ are  zero vanishes  $f$ vanishes on a neighborhood $U$. This implies the subset $C$ where all the derivatives vanish is open. The argument in the answer of Jonathan shows that this subset is also closed, so if the function is defined on a connected set, it is identically zero.

Comment: @YaG The function $f(z)$ and the zero function coincide on $U$. Therefore by the analytic continuation they must coincide everywhere.